# Curious missed optimization of recursive constexpr function by Clang

Tags: c++, clang, compiler-optimization, constexpr, clang++

Today I wanted to test, how Clang would transform a recursive power of two function and noticed that even with known exponent, the recursion is not optimized away even when using constexpr.

```
#include <array>
constexpr unsigned int pow2_recursive(unsigned int exp) {
    if(exp == 0) return 1;
    return 2 * pow2_recursive(exp-1);
}

unsigned int pow2_5() {
    return pow2_recursive(5);
}
```

pow2_5 is compiled as a call to pow2_recursive.

```
pow2_5():                             # @pow2_5()
        mov     edi, 5
        jmp     pow2_recursive(unsigned int)     # TAILCALL
```

However, when I use the result in a context that requires it to be known at compile time, it will correctly compute the result at compile time.

```
unsigned int pow2_5_arr() {
    std::array<int, pow2_recursive(5)> a;
    return a.size();
}
```

is compiled to

```
pow2_5_arr():                        # @pow2_5_arr()
        mov     eax, 32
        ret
```

Here is the link to the full example in Godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/fcKef1

So, am I missing something here? Is there something that can change the result at runtime and a reason, that pow2_5 cannot be optimized in the same way as pow2_5_arr?

Comment: Given that [gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/KTefPd) optimizes, I doubt there's anything preventing clang from doing the same.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations enabled?

Comment: Are you sure about the tail call? The last operation is multiplying.

Comment: @JesperJuhl Yes, I specified "-O3".

Comment: @Quimby The tail call comment was added in the output of Godbolt, I did not write that comment myself.

Comment: @Ikaros Oh, I see, it is at the call site, missed that.

Comment: You might just be missing a simpler syntax for forcing it to compile-time: `unsigned int pow2_5() { constexpr auto x = pow2_recursive(5); return x; }`  No `std::array` objects needed.